# Reading element one by one in JsonArray

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have below JSON returned by API call.

```
String jsonString="{\r\n" + 
        "    \"count\": 100,\r\n" + 
        "    \"limit\": 100,\r\n" + 
        "    \"totalResults\": 225,\r\n" + 
        "    \"hasMore\": true,\r\n" + 
        "    \"items\": [\r\n" + 
        "        {\r\n" + 
        "            \"id\": \"55D40522-8672-48B0-B225-FD3CE6686AD6\",\r\n" + 
        "            \"name\": \"AcmeHCMExtended\",\r\n" + 
        "            \"version\": \"20.01.01.03\",\r\n" + 
        "            \"status\": \"DRAFT\"\r\n" + 
        "        },\r\n" + 
        "        {\r\n" + 
        "            \"id\": \"2DB4C83B-0CF9-4A8E-AC41-A29B30324121\",\r\n" + 
        "            \"name\": \"AFinancialBot\",\r\n" + 
        "            \"version\": \"1.0\",\r\n" + 
        "            \"status\": \"DRAFT\"\r\n" + 
        "        },\r\n" + 
        "        {\r\n" + 
        "            \"id\": \"7EA85B81-3CA1-4BE0-B095-217E7C93DCEF\",\r\n" + 
        "            \"name\": \"AIAMFG\",\r\n" + 
        "            \"version\": \"1.0\",\r\n" + 
        "            \"status\": \"DRAFT\"\r\n" + 
        "        }"
```

I want to read  name one by one under the itmes. I am using below code.

```
JsonObject obj=Json.parse(jsonString).asObject();
 JsonArray items=obj.get("items").asArray();
System.out.println(items);   //it prints everything under items.
`System.out.println(items.name); `  //It gives error
```

I am not able to iterate item array. it does not show length property of array.

Can you guide me how can I access element one by one.

Comment: From where do you import Json, JsonObject and JsonArray?

Comment: @simdevmon  import com.eclipsesource.json.Json;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the `javax.json.JsonArray` APIs or something similar.  If so:

```
JsonArray items = obj.get("items").asArray();

for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(items.getJsonObject(i));
}
```

Note that `JsonArray` implements `java.util.List` and you are getting the size using the standard `List` API method.

The same code would work with `com.google.gson.JsonArray` ... though this class does NOT implement `List`.  Alternatively, you could make use of the fact that `com.google.gson.JsonArray` implements `Iterable` and write a "for each" loop:

```
for (JsonElement e: items) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

The equivalent code for `org.json.JSONArray` uses `length()` instead of `size()`.

---

In all cases, you should be able to answer your own question by searching for and reading the javadocs for the JSON library that you are using.

---

**UPDATE** - Apparently you are using the `com.eclipsesource.minimal-json`.  According to this [javadoc](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.eclipsesource.minimal-json/minimal-json/0.9.4/com/eclipsesource/json/JsonArray.html), it has a `size()` method and implements `Iterable`.